# OnAfterRender OnAfterRenderAsync in Blazor Component (Radzen)

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a list of users and I want to show the number of the list in RadzenTextBox.
something like this:

`<RadzenTextBox @bind-Value=@total Style="width: 80px; text-align: right" Change=@(args => OnChange(args)) />`

So @total is the number of users and I set it in OnInitialized()

Then I add one user to the list and I set @total again in OnAfterRender() or OnAfterRenderAsync(). @total was changed (I console in OnAfterRender() ) but my view dont re-render.

It only renders when I add the second time. I dont know why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that when you set `total` in `OnAfterRender` (it is literally after render), the component does not know that state was changed again and will not reflect `total's` new value.

It explains why `total` is always 1 "render" behind.

To solve that, you can:

- set `total` in OnParametersSet(Async) or during EventCallback
- after you set `total`, call `StateHasChanged()`

Note: You can call `StateHasChanged()` even in `OnAfterRender` though I do recommend avoiding that unless there is no other option.

I also recommend checking [this](https://knowledgebasehavit.files.wordpress.com/2019/11/blazor-component-lifecycle-diagram.png) brilliant poster by @RobertHaken, which explains everything.

Comment: Yep, Thx. This is what i want to know :D 
I use call StateHasChanged() in OnAfterRender() and it works

Comment: Just FYI, calling StateHasChanged from OnAfterRender is the only way to do it if binding is dependent on browser local storage, since that storage is not available before JS Interop is operational. imho,  they need another event happening after render

Comment: yea, I can confirm this thing is pretty ugly. All my components with jsinterop have something like "IsSecondRender" property. So then firstRender arg in OnAfterRender is used to just call StateHasChanged where "real" OnAfterRender happens :-D Without that server pre-rendering is not possible.